# how i can insert data automatically in junction table with many to many relation

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

can I insert date with trigger or something else the primary key of pharmacy table pharmacy-id and the       primary key of medicine table in the third table "pharmacy-medicine" which contains "pharmacy-id" and "         medicine-id" as a foreign key

[[create pharmacy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNH2.png)
[create medicine table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxuwA.png)
[create junction table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO6ir.png)](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text appropriately formatted. Show sample data the result you are trying to achieve and the SQL you’ve managed to write so far